# Epson L3256 Driver for Ubuntu

Tags: epson

I am using the latest version of Ubuntu. I have an Epson L3256 printer. Where can I find drivers for both scanning and printing?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Epson website and [enter "L3256" at the search field](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX). I cannot directly link to the results page, but entering "L3256" suffices and you will be served available software including drivers (which are quite up-to-date).